# sharepoint 2013, how to change 'Number of items to display' for a list view programmactially

Tags: sharepoint, csom

sharepoint 2013, how to change 'Number of items to display' for a list view programmactially, either CSOM or powershell is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [View.RowLimit property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.view.rowlimit(v=office.15).aspx) to set a value that specifies the maximum number of list items to display in a visual page of the list view.

How to set `RowLimit` for a View via CSOM

```
public static void SetListViewRowLimit(Web web, string listTitle,string viewTitle,uint rowLimit)
{
    var context = web.Context;
    var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
    var view = list.Views.GetByTitle(viewTitle);
    view.RowLimit = rowLimit;
    view.Update();
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Usage

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(url))
{ 
     SetListViewRowLimit(ctx.Web, "Documents", "All Documents",10);
}
```

Comment: awesome, this is exactly what I want.